# Equations or process to determine the result of a collision between two objects?

Tags: physics, hard-science, materials

When looking to design armor - how can I determine whether a given ballistic object would completely stop, deflect into another direction, or penetrate another object given complete physical information on the two objects and nature of the collision, including material makeup, shape, or any other variables?

Even if we can't know *exactly* - due to various limitations - what equations or process would we use to go about making our best guess?

Comment: I'm interested to see if there is an answer for this.  When it comes to things like testing flak jackets, nobody trust any design unless it's been tested in a real application.  One thing which may help, if nobody has an overall solution, is exploring designing armor to be predictable.  For example, rely on one monolithic rigid plate (like a ceramic based vest), or many many layers of highly interwoven tensile fiber (like kevlar).  Those extremes often admit useful simplifications in modeling.  Trying to handle anything in between may become highly dependent on the exact materials.

Comment: @CortAmmon Me too - I'm suspecting the equations involved would be so extensive as to attempt to simulate, at the atomic level, two objects colliding - which is almost certainly unfeasible as of now. In that case I would also like some alternative to help provide at least a guess... as good of a guess as possible anyway.

Comment: What classes of ballistic objects and what classes of armors are you looking at?  Are we talking platemail vs an arrow, or are we talking a modern infantry armor?  Armor piercing weapoins also have different behaviors from non-armor piercing (obviously), being better at not wasting energy on the armor.  And of course, we have active warheads like those used in modern anti-tank rounds that use plasma jets to do the dirty work (and the corresponding reactive armor to make them less effective)

Comment: @CortAmmon I'm with you: the question could be improved with a bit more detail. Certainly could have made my answer shorter... :-) I did take the assumption that the OP is asking about a pure ballistic impact, based on how they worded their question, but, who knows, maybe they were thinking "tactical nuke" all along. :-)

Comment: @DoubleDouble You are correct to imply that classical physics (what I based my answer on) can indeed only go so far. However, the good news is, ballistic collisions (at least all those we have weaponized to date) occur on a macroscopic (visible) scale, and at speeds far slower than the speed of light. When stuff happens on a macroscopic scale at non-relativistic speeds like this, classical physics provides a *very* good approximation. If you want to shoot people with a hadron gun or something, *then* you might need to consider quantum effects and atomic interactions.

Comment: The answer is excellent, but there are so many factors that your question is almost impossible to answer. For hypervelocity impacts the impactor and the armour both start behaving like liquids, for example. A rough rule of thumb for very high speed impacts is that the actual penetrator only reaches its own size in depth (everything else is a result of the transfer of energy between the tow objects). And of course there are techniques to do strange things like making anti armour "long rod" penetrators "self sharpening". So "it depends" is indeed the best answer.

Comment: Free body diagram duh!

Answer (score 7):

#### Answer: It depends

While your question only requires fairly basic kinematics (physics), there *are* quite a few effects to consider. I can't cover them *all,* but I'll try to hit the important ones. This will be a longer answer!

#### Assumptions

Here's what I'm taking as fact before I get into the meat of my answer:

1. Your projectiles follow [ballistic trajectories only](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trajectory_of_a_projectile). In other words, once they leave the muzzle, catapult, whatever, that the only forces acting on them are gravity, air resistance, and whatever happens when they hit (or miss) their target. Otherwise known as the "no rockets" assumption.
2. Your projectiles do not contain any explosives, warheads, magic powder, etc. That is, only the substance (or substances, as with jacketed rounds, for example), determine what happens at point of impact.
3. Your targets do not employ any active shielding like force fields, kinetic damping, or other "magic" means of stopping, slowing or deflecting the projectiles. Thus, we're looking at a pure kinetic collision.
4. Your projectiles may travel at supersonic speeds, but they will not be traveling at relativistic speeds (significant fractions of the speed of light). If they were, the materials wouldn't make much difference.

I believe these assumptions are reasonable based on the wording in your question, and the `(physics)` & `(hard-science)` tags, but let me know if otherwise, as that could change everything.

So, what matters?

#### Mass and velocity of the projectile

**(high school physics)**

Before even considering materials, it's important to look at mass and velocity, as they make an enormous difference, no matter what materials you use. For my favorite discussion of the topic, see the very first What If? : [Relativistic Baseball](https://what-if.xkcd.com/1/).

First, let's look at the kinetic energy, $E_k$, of any projectile with a given mass (m) and velocity (v):

$$E_k = \frac{1}{2} mv^2$$

Informally speaking, **the more kinetic energy the projectile has, the harder it *can* hit.** I'll get to that suspicious-looking *"can"* in a second, but first, a quick observation:

**Velocity** matters more than mass. Since the velocity (v) term is squared, doubling the velocity will do more than doubling the mass. However, practical considerations mean ballistics designers strike a balance between the two.

### Armor Design

Now, again, before considering materials, here are some properties of the armor (or, more generally, of the nature of the collision) that will affect the damage done:

#### 1. Elastic vs. inelastic collisions (about that "can"...)

More information: [Elastic collision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_collision) (Wikipedia)

For maximum damage, *all* of your projectile's energy needs to be deposited into the target. In other words, the projectile needs to be completely stopped by the target. If that isn't the case, a smaller fraction of the kinetic energy will "sink in" to the target, and the projectile will be less effective.

Often deflection is accomplished with geometry: give your armor lots of sharp angles and round corners, and projectiles will tend to take glancing blows, and retain more of their velocity (and hence impart much less of their energy into the target.) A useful analogy here is billiard balls. Hit a ball thinly, the cue ball retains a high velocity, but your object ball doesn't go very far. Hit it dead on, the cue ball stops, and the object ball gets all of that energy (well, almost—nothing's 100% efficient).

In concrete terms, successful deflection increases the projectile's *final* velocity. That is, after it bounces off (or travels straight through) your target, it retains more speed. First, a numerical example:

Let's say it retains half (0.5) of its velocity and all of its mass (does not fragment). Then we can do some simple rearranging to see how much of that energy stays with your target:

$$\% E_{target} = 1 - \frac{\frac{1}{2}m(0.5 \times v)^2}{\frac{1}{2}mv^2} = 75\%$$

You can generalize or play around with that by changing the 0.5 to some other percentage between 0.0 (worst case for the target—all energy transferred,) and 1.0 (no energy transferred—a miss). Since most of those terms cancel out, this can be written more simply:

$$\% E_{target} = 1 - x^2$$

Where $x$ is the fraction of the original velocity, as a number between 0 and 1.

#### 2. Distribute the impact

Ballistics vests used by law enforcement are a good example of this. They have an armor plate that, when struck, is designed to distribute the energy from the projectile over a large (chest-sized) area. Without the vest, the bullet's energy would be focused on a $1cm^2$ area, and hence easily penetrate the body.

It's hopefully obvious that applying the same force over a smaller area will be more likely to result in a penetrating injury, thanks to higher pressure. If you need convincing, try to stab a balloon with a 1 kg baseball bat. Then try again with a 1 gram needle.

Vests and similar armor actually operate on *multiple* principles, but it's not that complicated. Vests:

1. **Distribute** the impact over a large area, already discussed.
2. **Deform and fragment** the projectile (the armor is a very hard substance so it can break up the projectile). When a projectile breaks up, it becomes many smaller projectiles, so now you do your energy calculations on an array of fragments instead of one projectile.

   - The vests also "catch" the fragments with tough fabric and rubbery material so they don't fly off and hit the wearer (or his/her partner) in the face.
3. **Decelerate** the projectile. Via several layers of "softer" materials, the vest essentially "crumples" (see below) to slow down the projectile a bit before it hits the hard armor plate.

Wearers of vests *still* experience significant pain and (usually) minor injury, but they're a great example of how you can use physics to completely change the nature of a ballistic impact.

#### Decelerate the projectile

As above, armor can attempt to decelerate the projectile by providing some kind of padding, or, like a car, the armor can deform ("crumple") under stress. What it's doing is converting the energy of that projectile into a small amount of heat, which reduces the more harmful penetrating or concussive effects that would injure or damage your target.

In classical physics, this is simply deceleration. If your crumple zone can slow the projectile down, you can plug a smaller $v$ into the earlier $E_k = \frac{1}2 mv^2$ formula. And, as you recall, a smaller $v$ makes a relatively big difference.

#### Projectile shape and spin

To have your projectiles fly straight and true, the shape will be important, and with many projectiles, imparting spin will keep them much more stable during flight. How your projectiles behave in flight, how much they're slowed down by air drag, and how fast they can travel, are all governed by something known as [external ballistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_ballistics). Since I believe you are more concerned with *armor* design, and this answer is rather long already, I won't go into detail on that, but let me know (or ask another question) if you need to know more about projectile design; it's something I've studied.

### Materials, finally!

I've left this for the end of my answer because, as you'll hopefully agree by now, there's a lot you can do with pure physics that doesn't depend on materials.

But materials *do* matter, of course! A full review of all known armor-grade materials known to man would of course be beyond the scope, here, but I *can* give you some general guidelines, especially now that I've gone over some of the essential physics:

Generally speaking, you can have a *hard* substance that will resist penetration but be more brittle, or a *soft* substance that isn't as strong, but is able to bend and deform so it doesn't shatter and fail completely. In conventional armor (or blade) design, you'll tend to see a mixture of different types of steel (different carbon content/heat treating process).

If you know what kinds of materials your enemy's ammunition is made of, you can choose armor that is harder than the ammo, to cause the ammo to deform or fragment. (Again, harder ammo (e.g., high carbon steel) will be more likely to fragment, softer ammo (e.g., lead)  will more likely deform.) If you can cause the ammo to fragment, the pieces will fly off in different directions, which will reduce the energy your armor needs to absorb. (Again, think of this as a higher final velocity, and/or a lower mass (m), as less of the projectile ends up going forward into the target.)

### Conclusion/Summary

Thanks for sticking with me through a very long answer-slash-physics review. If you value brevity, I apologize. In this case, I felt the longer answer was the right approach, since you asked for equations, and how all of the factors influence the projectiles and armor performance. Hopefully I've done my job well enough for you to come away with a decent grip on the subject. Do feel free to ask questions in the comments.

Comment: The mark of a true scientist: that answer is *it depends*

Comment: @PipperChip Ha! I'm just happy I got to write about sciencey stuff with a baseball bat, guns, *and* billiards all in the same answer.

Comment: My impression is that at lower velocities damage type and extent is dominated by projectile momentum.  While at high velocities it is dominated by projectile energy (which makes sense given $M = m \cdot v$ and $E = \frac{1}{2} \cdot m \cdot v^2$).

Comment: I hope to write a supplemental answer to expand on @type_outcast's excellent answer later today.

Comment: @Jim2B Good question. Actually, energy and momentum cannot be separated. *Both* quantities are a consequence of mass and velocity. With ballistic trajectories (at least on Earth), velocity always dominates. This comes as a consequence of the acceleration due to gravity: the speed you need to hurl a projectile (even at a maximal 45-degree angle) so that it will travel any appreciable horizontal distance is fast enough that the velocity will always dominate the equation. Add explosives, then the collision is no longer ballistic (even though the *trajectory* may be), and C-4 dominates. :-)

Comment: @Jim2B That said, I think your comment is trying to say that momentum is still an important quantity to consider, and I absolutely agree. In *any* ballistic system of gun-projectile-target, the variables are *extremely* complex and nearly impossible to control for, and a lot of research has gone into trying to tease these apart, with only partial success. To that end, I like your answer's treatment of some of the real-world attempts to create better armor.

Comment: There's a lot of great information here - I see how this is a much larger topic than I imagined. I'm hoping you can expand on one additional point - after distributing and determining the *E* that hits the armor, what properties of the armor should I be looking at to determine how it reacts? In other words, if I had, say, a 1cm thick plate of Iron - and determine a 2 gram bullet hits fully at 762 meters per second with the head hitting with a 6mm impact area - if I calculate out the *E*, how do I know if (and how much) the Iron crumples or whether the bullet pierces through the iron plate?

Answer (score 1):

I hope to flesh this answer out better later but I only have a few minutes to start on this right now.

### Rules of thumb

As a general rule of them the quality of materials like metals for use as armor can be approximated by the metal's melting point.

Superalloys > Titanium > Aluminum > Lead

Note there are many exceptions to this rule of thumb since some metals with high melting points make lousy armor due to brittleness (e.g. Beryllium) or other factors.

### Factors to consider

Modern armor is more of a "system" rather than a single material.  It was known since before WWII that the best armors had different qualities through the thickness of the material (e.g. high hardness at the front, high ductility at the back).

#### Conventional (momentum dominated damage) rounds

During WWII armorers worked on heat treatments that gave the often single sheet of steel these qualities.  In that regard, the armor on US warships was significantly better per unit thickness than that of the Japanese.  Some felt that the US's Iowa class' 12" main armor belt may have provided superior protection to that of the Japanese's Yamato class' 16" main armor belt.  No naval engagement got to test that theory.

Even during WWII considerable thought went into defensive systems to harden ships to weapons (e.g. torpedoes).  These involved many layers of protection, each providing unique benefits.  For instance:

> Each side of the ship was protected below the waterline by two tanks
>   mounted outside the belt armor, and separated by a bulkhead. These
>   tanks were initially planned to be empty, but in practice were filled
>   with water or fuel oil. The armored belt tapered to a thickness of 4
>   inches (100 mm) below the waterline. Behind the armored belt there was
>   a void, and then another bulkhead. The outer hull was intended to
>   detonate a torpedo, with the outer two compartments absorbing the
>   shock and with any splinters or debris being stopped by the armored
>   belt and the empty compartment behind it.

Modern ship defensive systems and Cobham Armor continue using this approach, layering materials each of which provided a specific "strength" to the overall defensive system design.

> Although the construction details of the Chobham Common armour remain
>   a secret, it has been described as being composed of ceramic tiles
>   encased within a metal matrix and bonded to a backing plate and
>   several elastic layers. Due to the extreme hardness of the ceramics
>   used, they offer superior resistance against shaped charges such as
>   high explosive anti-tank (HEAT) rounds and they shatter kinetic energy
>   penetrators.

Proposed composite armor
[image: Proposed composite armor]

#### Hypervelocity (energy dominated damage) Rounds

When defending against hyper-velocity rounds the energy involved is usually sufficient to completely vaporize both projectile and armor.  This robs the weapon of penetration ability but also robs the defender of many mechanisms of defending themselves.

The best armoring system currently devised for these types of weapons is called a [Whipple Shield](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whipple_shield).

> Whipple shields consist of a relatively thin outer bumper placed a
>   certain distance off the wall of the spacecraft. This improves the
>   shielding to mass ratio, critical for spaceflight components, but also
>   increases the thickness of the spacecraft walls, which is not ideal
>   for fitting spacecraft into launch vehicle fairings. The advantage of
>   a bumper placed at a standoff over a single thick shield is that the
>   bumper wall can shock the incoming particle and cause it to
>   disintegrate. This spreads out the impulse particle over a larger area
>   of the inner wall of the spacecraft.

This concept **HAS** been applied for use in the context of weapons of war.

### Final Thoughts

In many areas, a "first order analysis" can give you a very good understanding of the overall problem.  However, in matters of armor and defensive systems, this is not really true.  There's much to consider and even the equations involved don't give the researchers and engineers enough information to design these defensive systems.  Most of what we now consider "the best solution" has been found by trial and error rather than theoretical work.

Comment: Great research! However it's important to note that the "momentum-dominated" rounds you speak of are not ballistic projectiles. Torpedoes and many of the naval guns in question both use high-explosive charges. I still wouldn't want to get hit by a "dud" fired from the Japanese [Type 98 gun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/10_cm/65_Type_98_naval_gun), which fired a 13kg nose-triggered explosive projectile at 1km/s, but armor considerations for explosive rounds are quite different from ballistic collisions, which is what the OP asked for.